# exception during working with external system error libgdx IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, libgdx

I get this error
**exception during working with external system error libgdx** 
when I try to run the desktop version of a libgdx project on IntelliJ IDEA , I'm using **java sdk 1.8.0_66** 
on android it runs fine

Comment: Have you tried to run "File | Invalidate Caches"? Also please provide screenshot with the error.

Comment: here are the error [link](https://imgur.com/a/cB7hAcH)

Comment: maybe it has something to do with the last version of  libgdx using gradle:3.1.0

Comment: I notece that IDEA  install gradle 4.6, and that there was some error about gradle instalation when I use the libgdx installer,

Comment: i'm givin up, eclipse works fine with desktop but not android, intelli works fine on android but not on desktop, I think I'll use both

Answer (score 0):

Set Gradle wrapper to version 3.3